# Entry to Hong Kong

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, china, hong-kong

I have a pre arrival registration slip for Indian citizens to enter hong Kong. I wish to enter China via Hong Kong. But the slip says

> The issue of the notification slip is not a guarantee of the registrant’s entry to the HKSAR. The registrant is still subject to immigration control under the provisions of the Immigration Ordinance, Chapter 115, Laws of Hong Kong. In general, a person who intends to enter the HKSAR for visit must fulfil normal immigration requirements (such as holding a valid travel document with adequate returnability to his/her country of residence or citizenship; raise no security or criminal concerns to the HKSAR; have no likelihood of becoming a burden on the HKSAR, etc.), have a bona fide purpose of visit, have adequate funds to cover the duration of his/her stay without working and hold onward or return tickets (unless in transit to the Mainland of China or the Macao Special Administrative Region), before entry to the HKSAR may be granted."

Can anyone explain "unless in transit to the Mainland of China or the Macao Special Administrative Region" this part?

Comment: I have a valid visa for Mainland China.

Answer (score 4):

It is linked to the

> hold onward or return tickets

part

If you are staying in HK, you need to have onward/return tickets.

If you are *in transit to the Mainland of China or the Macao Special Administrative Region*, you don't need to hold any return/onward tickets.

Mainland china has a separate border control and they can ask for onward tickets from there. This just means Hong Kong won't be asking onward tickets, if your next destination is mainland china.

Comment: It seems very likely to me that you still need appropriate documents to prove that you are in transit (visa for Macao or PRC).

Comment: @JakeDot this is probably complex double language to say you need a visa or other document allowing entry into mainland China or Macao while not saying they are separate countries.